# Global Env Variables for amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am using the amplify CLI for my application with multiple envs. In my application, I have a couple of lambdas, some having their own environment variables that I have added via `amplify update function`. I have noticed that when you switch envs, you have to add the env values again once you do a push. This is very impractical and does not scale well as it can be annoying to create a new env and have to re add the env values. I was wondering if there is a way to add a global env variable that is accessible to all envs for your amplify project? By this, I mean that I would like to have an environment variable that does not require other envs to have to re add the values. Any help is appreciated, thanks.